# Matplotlib Live Plotting Slowing down over time

Tags: python, matplotlib

For a long time, I have been struggling with the live portability of **Matplotlib**. In between, I moved to **PyQt** and found several good solutions there.
However, now I'd like to write some very simple simulations and would like to keep track of the process.
The data that has to be tracked is a 2D point, so I would use Matplotlib's scatter method. The updating works quite nicely with fig.canvas.draw. However the more data points I have plotted the slower the plotting becomes.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.fig, (self.ax1, self.ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
    self.fig.show()
    self.fig.canvas.draw()
    self.main()

def main(self):
    c = 1
    for i in range(1000):
        self.ax1.scatter(i, c)
        self.ax2.scatter(c, i)
        c += 1
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        self.fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

The relevant code lines are shown. It really revolves around the `ax.scatter()`. To my understanding, the underlying plot object becomes larger and larger as continuously add points to a point where the plotting takes more time than actual data simulation. Is there a way to only plot the new points? I've read of options for line plots where people use `line.set_ydata` and manual axis updates. Is there something similar to scatterplots or is there may be an even more elegant way?

Comment: capture the artists returned by Axes.scatter and update their x- and y-data as you iterate

Comment: Turn interactive mode on. This will only plot the latest data. I suspect that with interactive off, `draw` may be redrawing the entire plot from scratch.

Comment: Also, for your example, `c = i + 1`. If the real relationship is not that simple, it is still probably better to do `for i, c in zip(range(1000), range(1, 1001)):` or whatever.